# Why does the Intellisense in Visual Studio not work when I code in Unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I want to work with Visual Studio for unity, Intellisense does not work.
[image]

Comment: I don't believe code completion/intellisense works for files not opened as part of a project/solution.

Comment: Because its seeing it as a miscellaneous file not c#. There is a lot on that subject

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the script through the editor-Assets. Probably you are opening it as a normal script instead of as part of the Unity project.